# Cross Correlation and Errors in Sycl part+ DPCPP

Tags: c++, sycl, intel-oneapi, dpc++

I try to write Cross Correlation function.
In my program I wrote a Map skeleton which wraps OneAPI calls hiding hardware targeting issues through some parameter specifying the kind of target (CPU or GPU/Accelerator).
The problem is that, in the Sycl part, the program through some errors and I cannot resolve them.
my code:

```
  <!-- language: c++ -->
    //Definition of function which apply filter on matrices
    template<class T>
    T applyFilter(std::vector<std::vector<T>> f, std::vector<std::vector<T>> g) {
        int n_rows = f.size();
        int n_cols = f[0].size();
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n_rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n_cols; j++) {
                sum += f[i][j] * g[i][j];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
    ;
    
    //function which print a specific part of my matrix
    template<class T>
    void print_matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T>> matrix) {
        int m = matrix.size();
        int n = matrix[0].size();
    
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                std::cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    
    }
    
    //Function which Slice a specific part of my matricx
    template<class T>
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> slice_matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T>> mat, int i,
            int j, int r, int c) {
    
        std::vector<std::vector<T>> out(r, std::vector<T>(c, 0));
    
        for (int k = 0; k < r; k++) {
            std::vector<T> temp(mat[i + k].begin() + j, mat[i + k].begin() + j + c);
            out[k] = temp;
        }
    
        return out;
    }
    
    //Start to produce for my Matrix  random numbers
    template<class T>
    void rand_fill_row(std::vector<T> &row) {
        std::generate(row.begin(), row.end(), []() {
            return rand() % 100;
        });
    }
    
    //A function that for each cell of my matrix execute to fill it with random numbers
    template<class T>
    void rand_fill_matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T>> &mat) {
        for_each(mat.begin(), mat.end(), rand_fill_row<T>);
    }
```

```
 //Definition of Map Skeleton
        template<class Tin, class Tout, class Function>
        class Map {
        private:
            Function fun;
        public:
            Map() {
            }
            Map(Function f) :
                    fun(f) {
            }
            //Overriding () operator
            std::vector<std::vector<Tout>> operator()(bool use_tbb,
                    std::vector<std::vector<Tin>> &img,
                    std::vector<std::vector<Tin>> &ker) {
                int img_row = img.size();
                int img_col = img[0].size();
                int filt_row = ker.size();
                int filt_col = ker[0].size();
                int out_row = img_row - filt_row;
                int out_col = img_col - filt_col;
                std::vector<std::vector<Tout>> out;
        
                if (use_tbb) {
                    uTimer *timer = new uTimer("Executing Code On CPU");
                    tbb::parallel_for(
                            tbb::blocked_range2d<int, int>(0, out_row, 0, out_col),
                            [&](tbb::blocked_range2d<int, int> &t) {
                                for (int n = t.rows().begin(); n < t.rows().end();
                                        ++n) {
                                    for (int m = t.cols().begin(); m < t.cols().end();
                                            ++m) {
                                        out[n][m] = fun(
                                                slice_matrix(img, n, m, filt_row,
                                                        filt_col), ker);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    timer->~uTimer();
                    return out;
                } else {
        
                    /* A 2D std::vector<std::vector<T>>
                     * does not have elements stored contiguously in the memory.
                     * Thus I define a vector<T> and operate on them as contiguous blocks.*/
        
                    //Define Buffer for
                sycl::buffer<Tin, 1> img_buffer(img.data(), img.size());
                sycl::buffer<Tin, 1> ker_buffer(ker.data(), ker.size());
                sycl::buffer<Tin, 2> out_buffer(out.data(), { out_row, out_col });
    
                //Profiling GPU
    
                // Initialize property list with profiling information
                sycl::property_list propList {
                        sycl::property::queue::enable_profiling() };
                // Build the command queue (constructed to handle event profling)
                sycl::queue gpuQueue = cl::sycl::queue(sycl::gpu_selector(),
                        propList);
                // print out the device information used for the kernel code
                std::cout << "Device: "
                        << gpuQueue.get_device().get_info<sycl::info::device::name>()
                        << std::endl;
    
                std::cout << "Compute Units: "
                        << gpuQueue.get_device().get_info<
                                sycl::info::device::max_compute_units>()
                        << std::endl;
    
                auto start_overall = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    
                auto event = gpuQueue.submit(
                        [&](sycl::handler &h) {
                            //local copy of fun
                            auto f = fun;
                            sycl::accessor img_accessor(img_buffer, h,
                                    sycl::read_only);
                            sycl::accessor ker_accessor(ker_buffer, h,
                                    sycl::read_only);
                            sycl::accessor out_accessor(out_buffer, h,
                                    sycl::write_only);
                                    
    h.parallel_for(sycl::range<2> { out_row, out_col },
                                    [=](sycl::id<2> index) {
                                        int row = index[0];
                                        int col = index[1];
                        
    out_accessor[row][col] = f(slice_matrix(img_accessor, row, col,filt_row, filt_col)
                                            , ker_accessor);
        
                                        });
        
                            });
                    event.wait();
                    auto end_overall = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
                    cl_ulong submit_time = event.template get_profiling_info<
                            cl::sycl::info::event_profiling::command_submit>();
                    cl_ulong start_time = event.template get_profiling_info<
                            cl::sycl::info::event_profiling::command_start>();
                    cl_ulong end_time = event.template get_profiling_info<
                            cl::sycl::info::event_profiling::command_end>();
                    auto submission_time = (start_time - submit_time) / 1000000.0f;
                    std::cout << "Submit Time: " << submission_time << " ms"
                            << std::endl;
                    auto execution_time = (end_time - start_time) / 1000000.0f;
                    std::cout << "Execution Time: " << execution_time << " ms"
                            << std::endl;
                    auto execution_overall = std::chrono::duration_cast<
                            std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_overall - start_overall);
                    std::cout << "Overall Execution Time: " << execution_overall.count()
                            << " ms" << std::endl;
                }
                ;
                return out;
            }
        
        };
```

```cpp
//The main part
 template<class Tin, class Tout, class Function>
        Map<Tin, Tout, Function> make_map(Function f) {
            return Map<Tin, Tout, Function>(f);
        }
        
        int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        
            std::cout << "The Exutable File! " << argv[0] << std::endl;
            std::cout << "The Device Is! " << argv[1] << std::endl;
            std::cout << "The Fist Vector Size! " << argv[2] << std::endl;
            std::cout << "The Second Vector Size! " << argv[3] << std::endl;
            //The Device
            std::string device = argv[1];
            // Image's row count
            int m = std::stoi(argv[2]);
            // Image's col count
            int n = std::stoi(argv[3]);
        
            std::vector<std::vector<double>> img(m, std::vector<double>(n, 0));
        
            // Filter's row count
            int k = std::stoi(argv[4]);
            // Filter's row count
            int l = std::stoi(argv[5]);
        
            std::vector<std::vector<double>> ker(k, std::vector<double>(l, 0));
        
            //std::vector<std::vector<T>> out(r, std::vector<T>(c, 0));
        
            rand_fill_matrix(img);
            rand_fill_matrix(ker);
    /*Error is : no matching function for call to 'make_map'*/
        <!-- language: lang-js -->
            auto m1 = make_map<double, double>(applyFilter);
    <!-- language: lang-js -->
            std::vector<std::vector<double>> r = m1(true, img, ker);
            //print the result
            //for (auto &e : r) {
            //std::cout << e << " ";
            //}
            return 0;
        }
```

The Errors are:

no matching constructor for initialization of 'sycl::buffer

```
//Define Buffer for
            sycl::buffer<Tin, 1> img_buffer(&img[0], img.size());
            sycl::buffer<Tin, 1> ker_buffer(&ker[0], ker.size());
            sycl::buffer<Tin, 2> out_buffer(out.data(), sycl::range<2>{ out_row, out_col });
```

======================================================

```
non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
```

```
h.parallel_for(sycl::range<2> { out_row, out_col },
                                [=](sycl::id<2> index) {
                                    int row = index[0];
                                    int col = index[1];
```

==============================================

```
  Invalid arguments '
    Candidates are:
    std::vector<std::vector<#0,std::allocator<#0>>,std::allocator<std::vector<#0,std::allocator<#0>>>> slice_matrix(std::vector<std::vector<#0,std::allocator<#0>>,std::allocator<std::vector<#0,std::allocator<#0>>>>, int, int, int, int)

'
```

```
  out_accessor[row][col] = f(slice_matrix(img_accessor, row, col,
                                                            filt_row, filt_col),
                                                    ker_accessor);  }); });
```

===================================================

```cpp
no matching function for call to 'make_map'
```

```cpp
auto m1 = make_map<double, double>(applyFilter);
```

Comment: This is probably unrelated but you're doing really strange things with `uTimer`. Why are you including `uTimer.cpp` and not `uTimer.hpp`? Why are you using manual memory management at all in `uTimer *timer = new uTimer("Executing Code On CPU");`? Why are you manually invoking the destructor without `delete`-ing `timer` in `timer->~uTimer();`? Automatic storage (e.g. `uTimer timer = {"Executing Code On CPU"};`) should suffice, no need for clean-up.

Comment: Do you mind showcasing or highlighting which lines the compiler errors come from?

Comment: To increase the probability of getting an answer to your questions, I would suggest coming up with a minimum set of code that demonstrates the issue you are having. You have simply copied and pasted all of your code to the question, without highlighting where the errors are being flagged up. I am giving this advice so that you understand what will help you get a better answer. For this, if you can, post the minimum amount of code that you can compile to show the issues.

Comment: about uTimer it was my mistake. Thank you for pointing out

Comment: about manual memory management, I did not understand well. if it is possible share with me your information please

Answer (score 0):

Fix the first error by matching types - simply change your declarations of img_row, img_col, filt_row, filt_col, out)row, and out_col to be size_t instead of int.

For the second error - did the compiler also emit a hint as to the problem?  I had to make some assumptions based on your snipets, but I ended up with:

> error: no matching function for call to 'make_map' note: candidate
> template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'Function'

That tells me that we need to add more than Tin and Tout (<double,double>) - we need to specify the type of the function as well.
something like

> auto m1 =
> make_map<double,double,double(std::vectorstd::vector<double>,std::vectorstd::vector<double>)>(applyFilter);

but that isn't quite right in my mock up of your code.
You should try something like that.

If you still have an issue - please provide a full code example that we can try compiling.
If you fix it - please post back here what you found so we can all learn together.